# How to validate this configuration value?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .net 8 web application. In the Program.cs I have the following code:

```
var applicationName = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DataProtection:ApplicationName");
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName(applicationName);
```

How can this code be re-written so `applicationName` becomes validated in a correct way. The only rule is that it should not be null or empty.

I have seen that .net 8 has some new stuff for validating options and configurations. How could that be applied in this scenario?

Comment: @DenisMicheal The problem is that the value could be null or empty. In that case I want to show/handle the error in a correct way.

Comment: And what's the problem with simply using `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationName)) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Application name is required")` ???

Comment: @Tseng I could do that, but I know there are some new features in .net 8 for validating configurations, so that the code becomes more readable and less redundant. I just wonder how/if it could be used in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ValidateDataAnnotations` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Example define poco as you needed

```
public class DataProtectionOptions
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The ApplicationName for data protection is required.")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

Bind and validate configuration

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<DataProtectionOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DataProtection"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

Comment: This seems like what I am looking for. But how/where comes the actual setting: .AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName(...)?  Will that part remain as before?

Comment: Yes first line is going to be advanced validation